# Get active filters in observer in magento

Tags: php, magento, layered-navigation

I want to change my category display mode if there is active filters. I have my config.xml event is :

```
    <events>
        <catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <mycustom_module_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Mycustom_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setCategoryDisplayMode</method>
                </mycustom_module_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
    </events>
```

And my observer is method is :

```
public function setCategoryDisplayMode(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')
        ->getState()
        ->getFilters();
    if (!empty($appliedFilters)) {
        $category->setDisplayMode("PRODUCTS");
    }
}
```

But I am unable to get active filters with `$appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();` Is I am doing something wrong or my event is wrong?

I also tried with `Mage::getSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_State')->getActiveFilters();` but no success.

Answer (score 0):

There is no suitable single event in Magento for what you're trying to do. There is an alternative to it. Add following layout update via  `local.xml` file:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="namespace_module/category" name="namespace.module.category.cmsblock" before="-"/>
     </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

And create a block which extends from `Mage_Cms_Block_Block` class.

```
class Namespace_Module_Block_Category extends Mage_Cms_Block_Block
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        $filters = array();
        $appliedFilters = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getState()->getFilters();
        if (!empty($appliedFilters)) {
            $category->setDisplayMode("PRODUCTS");
        }
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```